# npm - yo - yeoman-environment/generator error

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

**npm ERR! peer dep missing: yeoman-environment@^3.2.0, required by yeoman-generator@5.4.1**

When I check the list of npm package available with command 'npm list -g --depth=0', I get the above mentioned error.

Can someone please help me understand it?

Comment: Can you run `npm install yeoman-environment`?

Comment: Thanks esqew. yeah before trying that I wanted to understand what did I miss that I have to install yeoman-environment separately? I am new to yeoman and related stuff. Just followed guidelines to install yo and generator-code.  Wasn't that enough?

Comment: In certain versions of `npm`, peer dependencies aren't installed by default. If you're seeing errors about it, you'd have to install them manually *or* update to the latest major release of `npm`.

Comment: I got a few warning      -- npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.                                  But it looked like I got it installed. + yeoman-environment@3.5.1
added 343 packages from 261 contributors and audited 343 packages in 130.74s      Bt I stl get same previ error.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved now.
I have uninstalled yo and generator-code first.
Then I have updated nodejs and npm version to LTS version.
Then again installed yo and generator-code. It gave the same warning that required yeoman-environment was missing.
I have installed yeoman-environment.
Now everything is alright. I am able to use yo and generator-code.